# How to loop on SQL Records according to an ID referencing two different tables and display results in a repeater or label

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, loops

I'm having a creativity shortcut now, so I hope you can help me!

I have three tables:

Table1

ID (int)
ContentType (int)
Title (varchar)
Subtitle (varchar)
TableA
ID (int)
IDCont (int) - references de ID column on table 1
Title (varchar)
Subtitle (varchar)

TableB
ID (int)
IDCont (int) - references de ID column on table 1
Title (varchar)
Subtitle (varchar)

The user can create a new "TypeA" or "TypeB" content that will be stored on TableA an add other sub-contents to it. So, if the users creates a typeA content, the data stored will be:

dbo.Table1
ID (1)
ContentType (1)
Title (this is a content type a)
Subtitle (this is the subtitle for it)

And now, the user will add 5 contents to this title, as they are a typeA content they will be stored in dbo.TableA
Same happens if the user creates a typeB content.

Now, I need to create the control to add it to the contents.aspx page, that renders the results according to the type of content created.

I was thinking of a loop that checks the Table1, if it finds a typeA content, then it must print all the contents related to it, but must not repeat the principal title (stored in table1).

A repeater control will repeat the principal title, so I need to bound the results and print them in one control, looping through typeA and typeB.

Help!

Comment: Are you using LINQ to SQL, or EF?  Are you allowed/willing to make a SQL VIEW to simplify this query?

Comment: Yes, LINQ. And yes also! Thank you tgolisch